# How to assign roles from helper class,MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing something like in action(Get),

```
[Authorize(Roles = SmartRoles.smclientadmin,SmartRoles.smclientbranchadmin)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
        return View();
}
```

And Helper Class

```
public class SmartRoles
{
public static string smclientadmin 
{ get { return smclientadmin; } 
set { smclientadmin = "SMClientAdmin"; } }

public static string smclientbranchadmin 
{ get { return smclientbranchadmin; } 
set { smclientbranchadmin = "SMClientBranchAdmin"; } }

public static string smclientoperator 
{ get { return smclientoperator; } 
set { smclientoperator = "SMClientOperator"; } }    
}
```

> Error its giving is "name attribute argument expected".... Is there a
>   right way to use this method?? If so please help...thanks for your
>   time...

Comment: You will have infinite loop when you would fetch any property values...! Instead of using this kind of confusing static properties use constant strings initialized to some string.

Comment: It would need to be `public static string smclientadmin { get { return "SMClientAdmin"; } }` but an enum might be better here

Comment: Thanks for reply.....@Stephen Muecke please post it as answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You creating an infinite loop (the getter is calling itself). Change the getter to return a value (no setter is required)

```
public static string smclientadmin 
{ 
  get { return "SMClientAdmin"; } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The property accesors would end up in a recursive call. Also, the attribute arguments must be constant expression. Change your code to as below:

```
        [Authorize(Roles = SmartRoles.smclientadmin)]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public class SmartRoles
        {
            public const string smclientadmin = "SMClientAdmin";


            public const string smclientbranchadmin = "SMClientBranchAdmin";

        }
```